# Unity3D Google cardboard app crashes on iPhone when changing scenes

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I developed a Google cardboard app using **Unity3D**, but when I build it on my iPhone, the app shuts down while it is changing scenes:

[image]

But, it works in Unity PC, even though there are some shader problems.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: the problem of shader I can fix it by Generating Lighting

Comment: are the scenes added in build settings?

Comment: Yes , I added all the scenes I used.